# Need help to understand this piece of code in MVCContrib Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, delegates, action

I'm a bit new to the concept of "Action" in C# and delegate in general.

I'm trying to study how to build a custom html component in MVC, and I chose the grid component of MVCContrib to start.

To add columns, typically we do

```
 <%= Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(model => model.Date).Format("{0:d}");
                column.For(model => model.DayAmount);
                column.For(model => model.LeaveType);
            })
            %>
```

and I see the source of Columns like the following

```
public IGridWithOptions<T> Columns(Action<ColumnBuilder<T>> columnBuilder)
        {
            var builder = new ColumnBuilder<T>();
            columnBuilder(builder);

            foreach (var column in builder)
            {
                if (column.Position == null) 
                {
                    _gridModel.Columns.Add(column);
                } 
                else
                {
                    _gridModel.Columns.Insert(column.Position.Value, column);   
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
```

What I'm confused of is the Action parameter  In this instance, Type is CustomBuilder, so when did the "CustomBuilder" object got instantiated?

I suppose,  i can rewrite the calling statement above as

```
Html.Grid(Model).Columns(delegate(CustomBuilder<T> column)
{
});
```

or a bit more explicit as

```
Html.Grid(Model).Columns(new Action<CustomBuilder<T>>(delegate(CustomBuilder<T> column)
                      {
                      });
);
```

So are we saying, when the Action was instantiated with the "new" keyword above, the param "CustomBuilder" was instantiated as well?

Lastly, in the

"`public IGridWithOptions<T> Columns(Action<ColumnBuilder<T>> columnBuilder)`"

function,

the first two lines are

```
var builder = new ColumnBuilder<T>();
columnBuilder(builder);
```

What do they do? Looks like it's instantiating ColumBuilder object and pass it as a parameter to Action method columBuilder. Is this where you instantiate the parameter?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after read this excellent article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio

while it's talking about Func, the concept applies to Action, which does not return any results.

Looks like the magic happens here

var builder = new ColumnBuilder();
columnBuilder(builder);

I obviously didn't understand the fact that delegate, is just a pointer to a function (anonymous or not). You still need to supply the parameter when calling it. (Duh!).

All cleared up now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with action concept.
The delegates is present in .net from the beginning so you should start with the first step. Should build the wall before the roof.
[Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)
[Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)
But you should know about generic classes and methods, extension methods...

Comment: @Thanks Peter. I read all the articles, still have a hard time connecting the dots in concrete examples like above which is the way I learn. Thanks anyway.